# Optimize a Sql subquery containing multiple inner joins and aggregate functions

Tags: optimization, sql

I have a select statement which is infact a subquery within a larger select statement built up programmatically. The problem is if I elect to include this subquery it acts as a bottle neck and the whole query becomes painfully slow.

An example of the data is as follows:

```
Payment
.Receipt_no|.Person |.Payment_date|.Type|.Reversed| 
          2|John    |01/02/2001   |PA   |         |
          1|John    |01/02/2001   |GX   |         |
          3|David   |15/04/2003   |PA   |         |
          6|Mike    |26/07/2002   |PA   |R        |
          5|John    |01/01/2001   |PA   |         |
          4|Mike    |13/05/2000   |GX   |         |
          8|Mike    |27/11/2004   |PA   |         |
          7|David   |05/12/2003   |PA   |R        |
          9|David   |15/04/2003   |PA   |         |
```

The subquery is as follows :

```
select Payment.Person, 
Payment.amount 
from Payment
inner join (Select min([min_Receipt].Person) 'Person',
   min([min_Receipt].Receipt_no) 'Receipt_no' 
   from Payment [min_Receipt] 
   inner join (select min(Person) 'Person', 
      min(Payment_date) 'Payment_date' 
      from Payment
      where Payment.reversed != 'R' and Payment.Type != 'GX' 
      group by Payment.Person) [min_date] 
   on [min_date].Person= [min_Receipt].Person and [min_date].Payment_date = [min_Receipt].Payment_date 
   where [min_Receipt].reversed != 'R' and [min_Receipt].Type != 'GX' 
   group by [min_Receipt].Person) [1stPayment] 
on [1stPayment].Receipt_no = Payment.Receipt_no
```

This retrieves the first payment of each person by .Payment_date (ascending), .Receipt_no (ascending) where .type is not 'GX' and .Reversed is not 'R'. As Follows:

```
Payment
.Receipt_No|.Person|.Payment_date
          5|John   |01/01/2001
          3|David  |15/04/2003
          8|Mike   |27/11/2004
```

<strike>I am unable to move the subquery out to a temporary table as temporary tables are simply not supported within the programming language used by my application.</strike>

**Edit :** Incorrect statement. Temporary tables are supported and therefore this is a valid option.

### [Following a post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272553/optimise-sql-sub-query-containing-inner-joins-and-aggregate-functions) -

The Query was rewritten as the following.

Query 1.

```
select min(Payment.Person) 'Person',
    min(Payment.receipt_no) 'receipt_no'
from
    Payment a
where
    a.type<>'GX' and (a.reversed not in ('R') or a.reversed is null)
    and a.payment_date = 
      (select min(payment_date) from Payment i 
      where i.Person=a.Person and i.type <> 'GX' 
      and (i.reversed not in ('R') or i.reversed is null))
group by a.Person
```

I added this as a subquery within my much larger query, however it still ran very slowly. So I tried rewriting the query whilst trying to avoid the use of aggregate functions and came up with the following.

Query 2.

```
SELECT
    receipt_no,
    person,
    payment_date,
    amount
FROM
    payment a
WHERE 
    receipt_no IN 
      (SELECT 
           top 1 i.receipt_no 
       FROM 
           payment i 
       WHERE 
           (i.reversed NOT IN ('R') OR i.reversed IS NULL) 
           AND i.type<>'GX' 
           AND i.person = a.person 
       ORDER BY i.payment_date DESC, i.receipt_no ASC)
```

Which I wouldn't necessarily think of as being more efficient. In fact if I run the two queries side by side on my larger data set Query 1. completes in a matter of milliseconds where as Query 2. takes several seconds.

However if I then add them as subqueries within a much larger query, the larger query completes in hours using Query 1. and completes in 40 seconds using Query 2.

I can only attribute this to the use of aggregate functions in one and not the other.

Comment: **What is the database type and version?** Also, have you looked into [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) or equivalent?

Comment: The Database I'm working with is Visual dataflex 14.0 with a Sql server 2008 R2 back end. However any Sql commands I use would have to be backwardly compatible to atleast Sql server 2005. Preferably sql server 2000 if possible.

Comment: I've never used RANK() before but I can definitely see myself using it again. Very useful thank you. I've added my rewritten Query using Rank() above.

Comment: FYI, `RANK()` is not available in SQL Server 2k. :(

Comment: Setting the [Date_Correlation_Optimization](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Db_Config_-_Date_Correlation_Optimization_Option) option to true within database>properties>options may also improved the overall speed without the need to rewrite the sub query.

Answer (score 2):

I see that in your question you said:

> *"I am unable to move the subquery out to a temporary table as temporary tables are simply not supported within the programming language used by my application."*

But, have you considered calling a stored procedure instead? Is this even an option, considering the limitations with the programming language?

If this is a viable option, you could simply have the results of your subquery inserted into a temp table transparently & encapsulate all the logic in the stored procedure.

---

**Edit**

I got to thinking about this some more, and perhaps the columns that you're using in your `JOIN` condition are of different collations. While this will usually result in a specific error message, there may be some implicit collation coversion occurring instead (see: [MSDN: Collation Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx)) between the sub-query & the data being joined.

Here are a few links about collation that might be useful to you:

- [Difference between collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and `Latin1_General_CI_AS`](http://www.olcot.co.uk/sql-blogs/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as)
- [Collation Hell (Part 1)](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/07/26/Collation-Hell-Part-1.aspx)
- [SQL SERVER – Find Collation of Database and Table Column Using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/16/sql-server-find-collation-of-database-and-table-column-using-t-sql/)
- [SQL SERVER – Change Collation of Database Column – T-SQL Script](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/20/sql-server-change-collation-of-database-column-t-sql-script/)

Also, you may be able to trick your programming language into using a temp table with syntax like this:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM tempdb..#MyTempTable
```

Just keep in mind that sometimes the temp database has a different collation then the data you're working with too, in which case you'll need to explicitly convert the data to/from each collation.

Comment: Completely agree with Alexander ...also tryin to add few index to speed a bit more

Comment: 2 people `completely agree`, but this answer has neither up-votes nor edits to improve whatever could be better explained? I'm baffled.

Comment: The statement I made with regards to my programming language not supporting temporary tables is incorrect and I have marked it as such. I'm not sure where I drew this conclusion from? Therefore using a temporary table is a valid option. From what I can tell there are no differences in collation between columns included in the joins. Though the information you posted on collation within Sql made for interesting reading most of which I was unaware of.